# Gnus to reuse same window for article buffer

Tags: gnus

I'm starting to use Gnus to read email. I've made this change so that I get the summary on one side of the screen and email on the other:

```el
(gnus-add-configuration
 '(article (horizontal 1.0 (summary .50 point)
                           (article 1.0))))
```

I have one problem with the article window. Sometimes I'd switch the buffer in that window to, say, read a file. If I leave the file buffer open in the window which previously held the article buffer, then when I go to the summary window and open a new email, the article buffer opens in a new window (split from the summary one), resulting in 3 windows. This is annoying; I'd like Gnus to reuse the same window as before for displaying article buffers.

Would it be possible to make Gnus open the article buffer in the window where the file buffer was shown?